A claimed physics of a mysterious letter (Arabic)
The pronunciation of the Arabic letter Dhad (ض) has sparked considerable debate, especially regarding its articulation in Modern Standard Arabic (MSA). Traditionally described as a fricative lateral sound, its modern pronunciation has shifted to a plosive, pharyngealized [dˤ] sound. Proponents of this contemporary articulation interpret classical descriptions to align with current pronunciation, suggesting that the tongue presses against the molars on both sides while its tip contacts the roof of the mouth, trapping air. They claim that as air flows from the lungs, it generates slight tongue movement, contributing a fricative quality that fits older descriptions. However, questions arise: Does air pressure indeed have enough force to move the tongue? Could this movement produce any frictiveness in the sound? And is this lateral positioning genuinely the reason behind Dhad's characterization as a side-originating sound? Supporters of the current articulation argue it embodies a true Ḍād sound with a subtle fricative edge. They also suggest that the pressure applied against the molars may play a role in its articulation, though it seems more aligned with producing a plosive sound than directly impacting the primary point of articulation.
Another unrelated question can we produce a plosive sound by the tongue without touching the gums or the palate, I mean purly dental?
Example of their ḍad: https://youtu.be/o5wX5K1BLRk
